# Can I use "Any()" method in asynchronous way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to make a duplicate-check method, so far I use:

```
private bool CheckDuplicate(string name)
{
    var result = _db.Foo.Any(f => f.Name == name);
    return result;
}
```

Is it worth/possible to make this operation in async way?

To my uderstanding (still learning), this method has to make trip through all entries in Foo table to check my condition, up to first found result. But on [Microsoft_EF_Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async) I read :

> Only operators which cause query execution have async counterparts.

I'm getting confused...

The db has dozens of thousands records to dig so far and it's growing.
I tried to find AnyAsync() method in EF but it seems not to be present.

Good day to all!

Comment: You mean this one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.anyasync?view=efcore-8.0

Comment: ` dozens of thousands record` is very, very little data. If the field is indexed you'll be able to search millions of rows

Comment: Is there an index on `Foo.Name`? With an index the query time should be fairly constant regardless of the number of records. Without an index you will have problems as the database grows, even if the query is async.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, thank you. You have also answered my unexpressed question about the list of async methods in EF. 
@ Panagiotis Kanavos - Understood now :)
@ JonasH - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckDuplicateAsync(string name)
{
    var result = await _db.Foo.AnyAsync(f => f.Name == name);
    return result;
}
```

I'm unsure why you weren't seeing `AnyAsync()`. As @gunr2171 posted in the comments, it should be available.

Comment: @vgwizardx You are correct. My fault. The object should be <IQueryable> and what I delivered under "_db.Foo" was not. Now I've got available AnyAsync() method. Thank you.